# Cannot control volume level with prosody in google Cloud Text-to-Speech

Tags: ssml

SSML Volume property has no effect on the output audio

Following is the `ssml`

```
<speak>
    <prosody volume = "+0dB"> This is a sentence with volume 10 For GOOGLE. </prosody>
    <s><prosody volume = "+6dB"> This is a sentence with volume 6 For GOOGLE. </prosody></s> 
    <s><prosody volume = "+24dB"> This is a sentence with volume +24 For GOOGLE. </prosody></s>
    <s><prosody volume = "+48dB"> This is a sentence with volume +48 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s> <s><prosody volume = "+196dB"> This is a sentence with volume +196 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s>
</speak>
```

And here is a sample code

```
  String ssml = $"<speak><prosody volume = \"+0dB\"> This is a sentence with volume 10 For GOOGLE.</prosody>" +
                $" <s><prosody volume = \"+6dB\"> This is a sentence with volume 6 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s>" +
                $" <s><prosody volume = \"+24dB\"> This is a sentence with volume +24 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s>" +
                $" <s><prosody volume = \"+48dB\"> This is a sentence with volume +48 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s>" +
                $" <s><prosody volume = \"+196dB\"> This is a sentence with volume +196 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s>" +
                $"</speak>";
```

Dubb(ssml);

```
    public static void Dubb(string ssml)
    {
        var client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();

        // The input to be synthesized, can be provided as text or SSML.
        var input = new SynthesisInput
        {
            Ssml = ssml
        };

        // Build the voice request.
        var voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
        {
            LanguageCode = "en-US",
            SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Female
        };

        // Specify the type of audio file.
        var audioConfig = new AudioConfig
        {
            AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Linear16
        };


        // Perform the text-to-speech request.
        var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);

        // Write the response to the output file.
        using (var output = File.Create("output.wav"))
        {
            response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
        }

    }
```

I expected that the volume will increase in each line, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
<speak>
    <prosody volume = "+0dB"> This is a sentence with volume 10 For GOOGLE. </prosody>
    <s><prosody volume = "+6dB"> This is a sentence with volume 6 For GOOGLE. </prosody></s> 
    <s><prosody volume = "+24dB"> This is a sentence with volume +24 For GOOGLE. </prosody></s>
    <s><prosody volume = "+48dB"> This is a sentence with volume +48 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s> <s><prosody volume = "+196dB"> This is a sentence with volume +196 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s>
</speak>
```

On the [TTS UI](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech#section-2) and it does work as expected.

[image]

From there you can export it to JSON (maybe it helps you).

```
{
  "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
    "pitch": 0,
    "speakingRate": 1
  },
  "input": {
    "ssml": "<speak> <prosody volume = \"+0dB\"> This is a sentence with volume 10 For GOOGLE. </prosody> <s><prosody volume = \"+6dB\"> This is a sentence with volume 6 For GOOGLE. </prosody></s> <s><prosody volume = \"+24dB\"> This is a sentence with volume +24 For GOOGLE. </prosody></s> <s><prosody volume = \"+48dB\"> This is a sentence with volume +48 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s> <s><prosody volume = \"+196dB\"> This is a sentence with volume +196 For GOOGLE.</prosody></s> </speak>"
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Standard-A"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the values "silent", "x-soft", "soft", "medium", "loud", "x-loud", or "default" are possible in the SSML language from google. This is sometimes more easy to use.  If you work with dB , you can get a distorted sound. A range from -40dB until +40dB is acceptable.

Here's an example

```
  <speak>
    <voice name = 'en-US-Wavenet-G'>
    <prosody volume = 'x-soft'>
     Hello stranger.
    </prosody>
    </voice>
    <voice name = 'en-US-Wavenet-G'>
    <prosody volume = 'loud'>
     I say it louder Hello stranger
    </prosody>
    </voice>
    </speak>
```